# How to install Filter::Crypto module for perl under ubuntu

Tags: perl

I use command:

```
cpanm --sudo --interactive Filter::Crypto
```

I am always asked for location of openssl.

Then I run command:

```
dpkg -L openssl
```

I get many paths.

I dont know what should I do next.

thanks

Comment: I tried with the default: `Where is your OpenSSL? [/usr] /usr`. I.e. `/usr` and it installed fine.

Comment: Do you type the path `/usr` after that question?

Comment: Yes I guess so (or just press enter, and the text in square brackets will be chosen). I did not use the `--interactive` option with `cpanm` so it chose the defaults automatically for me.

Answer (score 2):

To install this module, the develop files of openssl are needed. Under Ubuntu, it needs to install package: `libssl-dev` to get develop files to be installed: so after running `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`, the problem is resolved.

In CentOS, install `openssl-devel` package.